# build_android.sh Android NDK configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: android, android-ndk

I get this error from build_android.sh:

```
./build_android.sh
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /home/kkho/home/kkho/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130917/android-ndk-9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/kkho/home/kkho/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130917/android-ndk-9/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

configure: error: in `/cygdrive/c/Android_Native_Development_Kit_Cookbook/1505OT_CodeBundle/Chapter_8/PortingWithBuildSystem/jni/libbmp-0.1.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

I'm running the script on windows with cygwin, please help me!

The build_android.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
NDK=/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/
export CFLAGS="-mthumb"
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8"
export CC="$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$SYSROOT"
./configure \
    --host=arm-linux-androideabi \
    --prefix=$(pwd) \
    --exec-prefix=$(pwd)
    #--libdir=$(pwd) \
    #--includedir=$(pwd)/include \
    #--oldincludedir=$(pwd)/include \
make clean
make 
make install
#$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so ../x264/libx264.a libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a libavfilter/libavfilter.a libswresample/libswresample.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog  --warn-once  --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a
```

Comment: please find `"whether the C compiler works"` in `./configure`. How does it do the check? You probably don't have one of the C compilers (for the host and for the target), or it is not in the path.

Comment: Cygwin is probably more trouble than its worth. Cygwin requires special handling because of qwirks in packages like GCC. Can you install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and set up a Linux VM?

Comment: Also, according to David Turner on the [NDK mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ), you should set `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`.